# How to update two tables together in Oracle?

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle, spring-boot

Query :

```
UPDATE TABLE_ONE 
SET DATE=?, URL=?,  TYPE=?, STATE=?, FEE=?, NAME=?, STATUS=?
WHERE ID=?";
```

Another table `TABLE_TWO` has columns -  `NAME`, `ID`, `FEE`, `STATUS`, `TOTAL`,I want that on running update all above fields specified in query plus `FEE`, `STATUS` of `TABLE_TWO` gets updated together. I'm using Spring.

Comment: you cannot update 2 tables at the same time

Comment: You can have 2 update statement inside `@Transactional` method that will get updated together

Comment: Can you please explain a little more ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use trigger for say Table1 & write a trigger if any update on table 1 call trigger to update the Table 2 data.

it starts like..
create or replace TRIGGER trigger_name
  after insert or update on Table1
  for each row
  ...

For complete trigger refer (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_triggers.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can't update 2 tables (more than one) in one statement, instead use 2 statements and call them inside method annotated with `@Transactional`

```
@Transactional
public void updateTables() {
    updateTableOne();
    updateTableTwo();
}
```

commit will happen when method exists for both tables.

See more about using [@Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained) in Spring

Other option is calling [oracle procedure](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data-access-with-jdbc/spring-call-stored-procedure.html)

> Spring provides various ways of abstractions on JDBC to call database stored procedures.

Example

> ```
> SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
>         .withProcedureName("MOVE_TO_HISTORY")
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: You can add both update statements in PLSQL procedure/function and execute the same in java code

Solution 2: You can add both update statements in a function and invoke the same

Answer (score 0):

Oracle way of doing that is an **instead-of trigger** on a view.

Here's an example based on Scott's schema.

First, I'll create a view as a join of two tables, `EMP` and `DEPT` (that's where *updating two tables together* comes into a game):

```
SQL> create or replace view v_ed as
  2    select d.deptno, e.empno, d.dname, e.ename, e.sal
  3    from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno;

View created.
```

Now, an instead-of trigger. I'm handling `INSERT` and `UPDATE`; you can add `DELETE` as well. It means that - when you insert into a view or update it, underlying tables will be the final target of those commands.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_io_ed
  2    instead of insert or update on v_ed
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if inserting then
  6       insert into emp (deptno, empno, ename, sal)
  7         values (:new.deptno, :new.empno, :new.ename, :new.sal);
  8       insert into dept (deptno, dname)
  9         values (:new.deptno, :new.dname);
 10    elsif updating then
 11       update emp set
 12         deptno = :new.deptno,
 13         ename = :new.ename,
 14         sal = :new.sal
 15         where empno = :new.empno;
 16      update dept set
 17        dname = :new.dname
 18        where deptno = :new.deptno;
 19    end if;
 20  end;
 21  /

Trigger created.
```

Some testing: `insert`:

```
SQL> insert into v_ed (deptno, empno, dname, ename, sal)
  2    values (99, 100, 'test dept', 'Littlefoot', 1000);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
        99 test dept

SQL> select * From emp;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        800                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.81       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD                       7698 22.02.81       1250        500
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.81       2975                    20
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28.09.81       1250       1400         30
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01.05.81       2850
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2450                    10
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09.12.82       3000                    20
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.81       5000                    10
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08.09.81       1500          0         30
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12.01.83       1100                    20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03.12.81        950                    30
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.81       3000                    20
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1300                    10
       100 Littlefoot                                     1000                    99

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

`Update`:

```
SQL> update v_ed set ename = 'Bigfoot' where empno = 100;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * From emp;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        800                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.81       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD                       7698 22.02.81       1250        500
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.81       2975                    20
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28.09.81       1250       1400         30
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01.05.81       2850
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2450                    10
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09.12.82       3000                    20
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.81       5000                    10
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08.09.81       1500          0         30
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12.01.83       1100                    20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03.12.81        950                    30
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.81       3000                    20
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1300                    10
       100 Bigfoot                                        1000                    99

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

See if it helps.